# Is there any way to do async operation in an Android Oreo geofence trigger?

Tags: android, geolocation, location, android-8.0-oreo, android-geofence

I have an app that has a Service being triggered by geofence transitions. In that Service, I start a LocationClient to get the clients latest location. After that, I do an async HTTP operation to talk to my server.

In Oreo, I get the "**Background start not allowed**" when the Geofence is triggered, so it doesn't work. Same with Broadcast receiver.

From what I can gather, my only option is an IntentService? But that can't do any async operations since it is killed as soon as the method exits.

My question: Is there *any way* for me to do an async operation/location lookup when a geofence is triggered in Oreo?

Answer (score 0):

Either use Foreground Services (with ongoing Notification) and call a background thread there.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    startForegroundService(serviceIntent);
} else {
    startService(serviceIntent);
}
```

Make sure you return something sensefull in onStartCommand use stopSelf(startId) after your async task finished, to prevent the service from beeing re-launched rather randomly. Also make sure you call stopForeground(true) to cancel the ongoing notification as soon as you are done.

---

Or use Firebase Job Dispatcher. Your JobService should extend SimpleJobService as this allready provides you with an async method! [Simple Job Service](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/jobdispatcher/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/SimpleJobService.java)

```
FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new 
GooglePlayDriver(getBaseContext()));
myExtrasBundle.putString(SetStatusService.MESSAGE, message);
Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
// the JobService that will be called
.setService(StatusJobService.class)
 // uniquely identifies the job
.setTag(StatusJobService.UNIQUE_ID)
// one-off job
.setRecurring(false)
// don't persist past a device reboot
.setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
// start between 0 and 60 seconds from now
.setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(0, 15))
// don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
.setReplaceCurrent(false)
// retry with exponential backoff
.setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
.setExtras(myExtrasBundle)
.build();
dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

And all you need to make your method async:

```
public class JobService extends SimpleJobService {

@Override
public int onRunJob(JobParameters job) {
    if (job != null) {
        Bundle extras = job.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
           callServer(extras)
        }
    }
    return RESULT_FAIL_NORETRY;
}}
```